# How to include a specific component in $router.push()?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a click event like so:

```
cancelEdit(){
this.$router.push({path: '/path/abc'})
}
```

The user is sent to a new "page" after click. However, is it possible to also load a specific component when he arrives to the new path? I thought I'd do something like:

```
    import ComponentHere from '@/components/ComponentHere.vue'
export default {
..snip..
  methods: {
    cancelEdit() {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/admin/feedback-maintenance', component: ComponentHere })
    }
```

This did not work in my attempt.

Comment: What do you mean by "load a specific component" ... vue-router is all about loading components for specific paths ... maybe  make it as a child for the existing one ?!

Comment: instead of component write `name` also define the name in the router file and it should display that component.